# Find tool - prevent the clearing of search text from jumping the scroll position back

Tags: intellij-idea

I've been using Android Studio for a while, but I'm currently using IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1.5. When I use the find tool (ctrl+f) and type text, pressing enter will jump to each next result.

However, if I clear the text (after, say, reaching the result I want to stop at) it just jumps (scrolls) back to the line in the file I was on when I started searching, mostly defeating the purpose of searching to begin with.

This was not my experience with Android Studio (I forgot the specific version but it was relatively recent). *I expect the find tool to behave like it would with any browser*, or really any other piece of software (i.e. clearing the text has no effect on the file's scroll position).

**Is there an option to disable/change this behavior?** It is incredibly frustrating...

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190270

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I didn't find anything related to this issue. Good to know I'm not insane.